# heroku login on mac terminal how to

Tags: heroku

We are new with Heroku.
I have installed the toolbelt on OSx.
I go to terminal which shows MacBook-Pro-de-Francisco-Balarezo:~ francisco$

I input $heroku login and i get login: that refers to mac user credentials not heroku.

I understand this is a basic stuff, we are doing our fisrt steps.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5):

To login to Herok issue `heroku login` from the command line. Enter your Herkou email / username. Press enter, then your Heroku password.

```
macbook-austin:~ aus$ heroku login                                                                                                    
Enter your Heroku credentials.                                                                                                        
Email: heroku.account@email.com                                                                                                      
Password (typing will be hidden): yourpassword                                                                                                    
Authentication successful.   
macbook-austin:~ aus$
```

Now you can run other heroku commands that require authentication.

The only reason heroku would be asking for your OS X credentials would be if you were running it with `sudo` or it was needing root access. This shouldn't be the case.